# exclude project references in solution on conditional c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, solution, visual-studio-app-center

I build xamarin app(uwp,ios,android) and use appCenter for builds and delivery. For certain reason i cant build android and ios project having uwp project included in the solution. Creating build configuration does solve an issue. Is its possible to have some conditional in solution file to include certain projects?

Comment: "For certain reason i cant build android and ios project having uwp project included in the solution" Let's try and figure that out first. What problem do you get when you include the UWP project?

Comment: Can`t build ios and android on appCenter because nuget restoration packages fail for uwp project. e.g: "UWP.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "_IsProjectRestoreSupported" does not exist in the project.". Without uwp its finely been built.  have a look here https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/issues/734

Comment: you can create multiple solution files - one without UWP and one with

Comment: Yeah, sure i can :) though i hoped for some elegant solution ...if its possible...

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/21180#issuecomment-950971023

Comment: kind of no idea how that is going to help me on appcenter :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Nuget restore issue with the latest Mono version.
You can try lowering the Mono version, used to build the application in Appcenter.
Go to AppCenter -> select Build from the left menu. Then choose a branch. At the most right you will see a setting icon. Click on it.
From there menu like this will appear. From the SDK version you can choose a different one.
[image: Appcenter Mono SDK version selection]